# Failover Mirror

Tags: sql-server, mirroring, failover

My question is about the failover process in SQL Server Mirror.

If just the database, not a instance or a server, goes offline or is unreachable, will failover occur to the secondary server or is it necessary that the whole instance goes offline?

Answer (score 2):

You wont be able to bring the database that is involved in mirroring OFFLINE. It will throw an error message saying that - the database is involved in mirroring and it cannot be offline.

In order to bring the database offline, you have to break mirroring.

If the principal database server becomes unreachable and you have witness configured to perform automatic failover, then it will initiate a failover.

HTH